# leaf([X,[], []], [X]). how to get the list of leaves of a tree?

Tags: prolog

I wrote this code for get the leaves of a tree.

```
    leaf([X,[], []], [X]).
    leaf([_, G, D], N) :- 
       leaf(G, N1), 
       leaf(D, N2), 
       mix(N1, N2, N3), 
       N is N3.
```

but when the this query is executed:

```
    ?- leaf([19, [18, [], []], [17, [], []]], N).
```

I get this error:

```
    ERROR: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[18,17]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character)
    ERROR: In:
    ERROR:    [9] _2656 is [18,17]
    ERROR:    [8] leaf([19,...|...],_2696) at e:/downloads/science/riag/university/1st master fond/1st semester/pp/tp/tp_prolog/tp1.pl:67
    ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
N is N3.
```

You are using `is` as an assignement operator.

But it does the following:

1. Evaluate the *arithemtic* expression on the right-hand-side
2. Unify the result with the left-hand side

You don't *need* assignement at all.

Prolog provides *logical variables* which behave the same as references to **global** variables in stateful programming languages.

So, you just change *whatever is named by* the name `N`:

```
    leaf([X,[], []], [X]).
    leaf([_, G, D], N) :- 
       leaf(G, N1), 
       leaf(D, N2), 
       mix(N1, N2, N). % UPDATE WHATEVER IS DESIGNATED BY N
```

The twist is that Prolog is assign-once:

- *whatever is designated by N* is a container (a memory cell)
- Initially this container is empty (aka. "the variable is uninstantiated" or "the variable is var", or `var(N)` succeeds).
- As the program proceeds the container is set to a term  (aka. "the variable is instantiated" or `nonvar(N)` succeeds). The term may be compley, i.e. a graph of (possibly filled) containers.
- You cannot unset the container's content except by making a previously done computation un-history, i.e. "by backtracking".

**P.S.**

```
`Type error: `[]' expected, found `[18,17]' (a list)
```

generated by SWI Prolog is really confusing. This may be due to the fact that one can write things like:

```
N is [a].
```

and `N` is unified with the (in SWI-Prolog, sanely Unicode) code point for `a`.

```
?- N is [a].
N = 97.

?- N is [97].
N = 97.
```

I think that was *de mode* to obtain (unwisely unspecified and unstandardized because EBCDIC is so hot in '95) codepoints in ancient Prologs. This should probably be burninated for good?

There is also the saner

```
?- N is 0'a.
N = 97.
```